# Given a jooq query how do find the tables involved?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am currently using a [DefaultExecuteListener](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) to hook into the jooq query lifecycle.  How do I reliably determine if the query is a select statement and what tables (org.jooq.Table) are involved in the select?

```java
@Override
public void executeStart(ExecuteContext context) {
    Set<Table> tables = new HashSet<>();
    if (context.query() != null) {
        context.query(); // How do you check if this is a select statement and retrieve the tables involved?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I reliably determine if the query is a select statement

You can do that in your `ExecuteListener` by checking `context.query() instanceof Select`

> and what tables (org.jooq.Table) are involved in the select?

As of jOOQ 3.15, the best way to access the expression tree during SQL generation is to implement a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/VisitListener.html). This article shows an extensive example of [how to implement client side row level security in jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/). You'll need less than that. In the simplest case, this might suffice:

```java
class TableCollector implements DefaultVisitListener {

    Set<Table<?>> tables = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void visitStart(VisitContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.queryPart() instanceof Table)
            tables.add(ctx.queryPart());
    }
}
```

Now, all you need is to glue these two together.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would associate invocations of VisitListener with an invocation of ExecuteListener on the same query?

Comment: To clarify: I need the tables involved at execution time.

Comment: @ScottWiedemann: Slow but simple solution: You could re-render the query with a derived configuration that has the `VisitListener` from within the `ExecuteListener`. Faster, but trickier solution: Find some way for the two listeners to communicate, e.g. use some thread locals, or some queue, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Jooq tables (org.jooq.Table) involved in a query at execution time by using a `VisitListener` and in conjunction with an `ExecuteListener`:

```java
import org.jooq.Table;
import org.jooq.VisitContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultVisitListener;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class TableCollector extends DefaultVisitListener {

    private final static ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<Table<?>>> queryToTables = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static HashSet<Table<?>> getTables(String sqlQuery) {
        return queryToTables.get(sqlQuery);
    }

    private <T> T getDataValue(VisitContext context, String key, T defaultValue) {
        T value = (T) context.data(key);
        if (value == null) {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
    }

    private <T> T putDataValue(VisitContext context, String key, T value) {
        return (T) context.data(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitStart(VisitContext context) {
        Integer stackSize = getDataValue(context, "stackSize", 0);
        stackSize++;
        putDataValue(context, "stackSize", stackSize);
        if (context.queryPart() instanceof Table) {
            Table<?> table = (Table<?>) context.queryPart();
            HashSet<Table<?>> tables = getDataValue(context, "tables", new HashSet<>());
            tables.add(table);
            putDataValue(context, "tables", tables);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visitEnd(VisitContext context) {
        Integer stackSize = getDataValue(context, "stackSize", -1);
        stackSize--;
        putDataValue(context, "stackSize", stackSize);
        if (stackSize == 0) {
            HashSet<Table<?>> tables = getDataValue(context, "tables", new HashSet<>());
            String sql = context.context().render();
            if (sql != null) {
                queryToTables.put(sql, new HashSet<>(tables));
            }
            tables.clear();
            putDataValue(context, "tables", tables);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import org.jooq.ExecuteContext;
import org.jooq.Query;
import org.jooq.Table;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListener;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TableExecuteListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {

    @Override
    public void executeStart(ExecuteContext context) {
        super.executeStart(context);

        // pull the tables from the {@link TableCollector} for this query
        final Set<Table<?>> tablesInQuery = new HashSet<>();
        if (context.query() != null) {
            tablesInQuery.addAll(TableCollector.getTables(context.sql()));
        } else {
            for (Query query : context.batchQueries()) {
                tablesInQuery.addAll(TableCollector.getTables(query.getSQL()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```